# How to fix including javascript file without encoded sign character in content?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a php file like `index.php`, in this file i included 1 `.js` file which contain some script to handle the html. Some of the contents in the .js file is Vietnamese characters.

When i load the page and the js file is loaded, i saw that all of Vietnamese have been encoded and the browser cannot display them properly, i also put the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in `<head></head>`, and also put `charset=utf8` in `<script></script>`.

Here is my code:
*** myfile.js***

```
var status1 = [
 {
   id: '1',
   name: 'Chờ duyệt'
 },
 {
   id: '2',
   name: 'Duyệt'
 }
]
```

*** myfile.php ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <!-- some other css, js including....-->
    </head>
    <body>
       <input id="show_stt" name="show_stt"/>
       <select id="cmb_stt">
         
       </select>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo __HOST_NAME ?>/modules/scripts/hoptacquocte/tddoitac/CanBoNhap.js"></script>
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#show_stt').val(status1[0].id);
            $('#cmb_stt').append('<option value="9999">'+status[0].name+'</option>');
          });
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result always show string "`ChА╩² duyА╩┤t`". Is there anyway to fix this, if i run source on my localhost it's fine, but when i run source on another pc then it occur.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Adding tags in the document itself to declare you use UTF-8 is probably the least relevant thing. Is your IDE or text editor actually saving all source files in UTF-8? Is your web server sending a Content-Type header with the right encoding?

Comment: Please, it's 2023 .. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">` (obviously change `en` as appropriate) - no need for HTML4 transitional blah de blah since HTML5 became "recommended" back in 2014

Comment: What makes you think this problem is related to PHP in any way? You haven't shared any relevant PHP code

Comment: can you also verify your file encoding. Insure that your file enconding is also UTF-8

Comment: I also check the encoding of file in Notepad++ and it's UTF-8

Comment: @NicoHaase i mean the configure of server, not the PHP code

Comment: I suggested two checks and you only did one. So it must be the other thing.

Answer (score 1):

Save your JS file with utf-8 encoding and the problem will be solved.
Notice that If the file saved with correct encoding, when you open JS file directly with browser, Vietnamese characters must have shown correctly.

Also

- you have to edit your question's tags and remove PHP tag.
- there are some typos in your code that should be fixed.

Comment: I also check the encoding of file in Notepad++ and it's UTF-8

Comment: This is your code hosted on my host and as you can see, UTF-8 characters are fine: https://mitrarank.ir/face/js/test.js